# Generic type assertion for react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I would like to have type-safe Input component with ref forwarding.

I would like to call it like below to have suggestions in props:

```
type FormData = {
   firstName: string
}

...

<Input<FormData> name="firstName" ... /> //support of suggestions for name prop
```

but it does not work. In code below I have an error that T is not generic. How to fix that?

```
// types.ts
import { FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";

export type FieldWithForwardedRef<T> = <TFormData extends FieldValues>(
    props: T<TFormData> & { // Error: T is not generic
        ref?: Ref<HTMLDivElement>;
    },
) => ReactElement;
```

```
// input.tsx
import { FieldValues } from "react-hook-form";

export type InputProps<TFormData extends FieldValues = FieldValues> = PropsWithField<
    TFormData,
    BaseInputProps
>;


export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, InputProps>((props, ref) => {
    return (
        ...
    );
}) as FieldWithForwardedRef<InputProps>;
```

or maybe there is a simplier way to connect forwardRef with generics ?